# How do I use a macro to expand a tuple to its members as function arguments?

Tags: rust, macros

I have a function from an external library [1] like

```
fn set_color(r: f64, g: f64:, b: f64)
```

I would like to manage my colors in tuples like

```
let yellow = (1., 1., 0.);
```

I thought of a macro like:

```
macro_rules! rgb {
    ( $rgb:expr ) => { rgb.0, rgb.1, rgb.2 }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d71e57c6f1207708848cbdf51997b307)

and then

```
set_color(rgb!(yellow));
```

Unfortunately Rust then says: `error: macro expansion ignores token ',' and any following`.

How can I make this happen?

---

[1]: `cairo::Context::set_source_rgb()` and friends

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you need a macro for this? Can a function suffice? `fn rgb(color_tup: (f64, f64, f64))`?

Comment: @chub500 how would you use that `rgb` function to call the provided `set_color` function?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: `set_color(color_tup.0, color_tup.1, color_tup.2);`?

Comment: @chub500 as I understand it, the point is that OP doesn't want to do that tuple unpacking for every function call.

Comment: I guess a better name for the wrapper would be `fn set_color_tup(color: (f64, f64, f64))`. I think this is a good usecase for a tuple struct even. If OP is worried about performance, this function inlined should be identical to the macro.

Comment: If it was only one function, I could wrap it. But `cairo::` has lots of similar functions.

Comment: Ahh that's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this. Rust macros are not C macros that perform dumb textual manipulation; Rust macros must result in valid Rust code and `a, b, c` is not valid.

The closest would be to pass in the function to the macro:

```
macro_rules! rgb {
    ($f:expr, $rgb:expr) => {
        $f($rgb.0, $rgb.1, $rgb.2)
    };
}
```

```
let white = (1., 1., 1.);
rgb!(set_color, white);
```

Comment: I think an ordinary function could accomplish this too. `fn rgb<T>(f: fn(f64, f64, f64) -> T, color: (f64, f64, f64)) -> T`