# Is there way to unfold/unpack slices?

Tags: rust, format

```
fn create_phone_number(numbers: &[u8; 10]) -> String {
    format!("({}{}{}) {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}",
        numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2],
        numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5],
        numbers[6], numbers[7], numbers[8],
        numbers[9])
}
```

I'm writing this simple function to print out a phone number. Is there a way to write it shorter? In Python, I can just unpack it, so it would look like:

```py
def create_phone_number(numbers):
    return "({}{}{}) {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}".format(*numbers)
```

Is there a Rust equivalent?

Comment: Related: [How can I spread a Vec<> into the arguments of format!()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67105073/11082165) and [How do I use a macro to expand a tuple to its members as function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61637160/11082165)

Comment: Side note, having a function return a `String` is often an anti-pattern in Rust. Writing a type with a `Display` implementation is better, because often you will take the returned string and format it into another string. Using `Display` instead allows you to write the formatted value directly into the larger string where it will actually be used, and avoid a temporary allocation. And, if you actually _do_ need a `String`, you can just call `.to_string()` on the `Display` value, and it winds up doing the same thing as `format!` anyway.

Comment: [Here's an example of what I mean](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=97f27e5648d9458ff6640b2d0fbd254f). With this you can call `.to_string()` on a `PhoneNumber` if you actually want a `String`, but if you're writing the phone number into a larger string, you can format the `PhoneNumber` directly, which avoids creating a temporary `String` to hold the phone number. You could even modify this wrapper type so that the conversion from an array is fallible, failing if any of the digits is > 9.